# IComparer<T> child as a generic param could not be used in Sort

Tags: c#, sorting, generics, mono

Got stuck trying to sort my `List<>` in C#.

I have an interface type with its implementation class:

```
public interface IRoom
{
    // ...
}

public class Room : IRoom
{
    // ...
}
```

And a base class for my comparers:

```
public abstract class RoomComparer : IComparer<IRoom>
{
    public RoomComparer()
    {
    }

    public abstract int Compare(IRoom x, IRoom y);
}
```

And two its children:

```
public class StandardMultipliedSquareMetersComparer : RoomComparer
{
    public StandardMultipliedSquareMetersComparer()
    {
    }

    public override int Compare(IRoom a, IRoom b)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class SquareMetersComparer : RoomComparer
{
    public SquareMetersComparer()
    {
    }

    public override int Compare(IRoom a, IRoom b)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, here's where the problems begin: I got a generic class `Hotel` with a list of my `Room` instances:

```
public class Hotel<TRoom, TComparer> : IHotel, IEnumerable<TRoom> 
    where TRoom : IRoom 
    where TComparer : RoomComparer, new()
{
    public List<TRoom> Rooms;
    protected TComparer Comparer;

    public Hotel(TRoom[] rooms)
    {
        Rooms = new List<TRoom>();
        Rooms.AddRange(rooms);
        Comparer = new TComparer();
        Rooms.Sort(Comparer);
    }
}
```

And here's the trouble - I got two errors on the line `Rooms.Sort(Comparer);`:

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List.Sort(System.Collections.Generic.IComparer)'
>   has some invalid arguments (CS1502)
>
> Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert`TComparer' expression to
>   type `System.Collections.Generic.IComparer' (CS1503)

I tried many different solutions, but no result. What's happening?

*Note*: using `Mono 3.10.0` on Ubuntu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to use generic contravariance for this (if a comparer can compare two `TRoom` values, it should be able to compare two `IRoom` values), which would *usually* be fine - but only when `TRoom` is known to be a class type. You can fix that by requiring that `TRoom` is a reference type:

```
where TRoom : class, IRoom
```

At that point, contravariance works fine, and all is well. It does require that all your room types are genuinely classes, of course.

Do you definitely need the hotel to be generic like this? It seems a little too much like overkill to me...

Comment: Why is it not fine for value types?

Comment: @Stilgar: Generic variance works on the basis that the same code can be used for all appropriate generic type arguments, without values needing to go through any conversions (e.g. boxing from a struct to the interface). It's just a limitation of the way that generic variance works in .NET.

Comment: So basically the compiler must be sure it would not need to generate boxing code?

Comment: @Stilgar: Or any other kind of conversion that actually changes the bits. The idea is that a `string` reference *is* an object reference already, so an `IComparer<object>` can be used to sort a `List<string>`, for example.

Comment: That's a pity, but I really need that complecity =(

Comment: And what if I need a `Comparer` on `Room` class, not `IRoom` interface? When I change my comparers and the `Hotel` definition, I got the same errors...

Comment: @shybovycha: We'd need to see *exactly* how you changed it - I suggest you ask a new question rather than editing your existing one, for clarity. (Feel free to refer back to this question but highlight the difference, to avoid it being closed as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to fix this:

```
where TComparer : IComparer<IRoom>, new()
```

(as for the *why*, see Jon's answer)

You could also simplify your code somewhat:

```
Rooms = rooms.OrderBy(room => room, new TComparer()).ToList();
```

(just add `using System.Linq`)

[See working demo](http://ideone.com/ZhApSN)

Comment: `RoomComparer` *doesn't* necessarily satisfy that constraint - if you have a `public struct ValueRoom : IRoom`, then a normal `RoomComparer` doesn't implement `IComparer<ValueRoom>`. (At that point my solution won't work either, of course.)

Comment: @Jon thanks for pointing that out, I didn't think about boxing