# IComparer<T> could not use class as a parameter

Tags: c#, oop, generics, mono

As I asked in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664104/icomparert-child-as-a-generic-param-could-not-be-used-in-sort), I got stuck with `IComparer<T>` implementation.

I got an interface and class, implementing one:

```
public interface IRoom
{
    // ...
}

public class Room : IRoom
{
    // ...
}
```

And a comparer parent-child classes:

```
public abstract class RoomComparer : IComparer<Room>
{
    public RoomComparer()
    {
    }

    public abstract int Compare(Room x, Room y);
}

public class StandardMultipliedSquareMetersComparer : RoomComparer
{
    public StandardMultipliedSquareMetersComparer()
    {
    }

    public override int Compare(Room a, Room b)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class SquareMetersComparer : RoomComparer
{
    public SquareMetersComparer()
    {
    }

    public override int Compare(Room a, Room b)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, I need to use my `IRoom` child and a `RoomComparer` child as a generic type parameters for this class:

```
public class Hotel<TRoom, TComparer> : IHotel, IEnumerable<TRoom> 
    where TRoom : class, IRoom 
    where TComparer : RoomComparer, new()
{
    public List<TRoom> Rooms;
    protected TComparer Comparer;

    public Hotel(int stars, TRoom[] rooms)
    {
        Rooms = new List<TRoom>();
        _stars = stars;
        Rooms.AddRange(rooms);
        Comparer = new TComparer();
        Rooms.Sort(Comparer);
    }

    // ...
}
```

But compilation fails on line

```
Rooms.Sort(Comparer);
```

with two errors

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List.Sort(System.Collections.Generic.IComparer)'
>   has some invalid arguments (CS1502)
>
> Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert`TComparer' expression to
>   type `System.Collections.Generic.IComparer' (CS1503)

From my point of view, OOP model is correct, and if an argument to `Hotel` class constructor implements `IRoom`, just like this: `new Hotel<Room, SquareMetersComparer>`, than it should be correctly passed to `RoomsComparer` class constructor and, then, `RoomComparer` should be correctly passed to a `List.Sort()` method. But compiler thinks in other way...

So, the question is: what's wrong?

*If this helps somehow:* I am using `Mono 5.10.0` on `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Comment: Is that correct that `RoomComparer` compares instances of `Room` class, but other comparers work with `IRoom` interface?

Comment: @James, `StandardMultipliedSquareMetersComparer` and `SquareMetersComparer` don't implement `public abstract int Compare(Room x, Room y);` so I guess that might be a problem or just not all the code was listed.

Comment: @takemyoxygen sorry, fixed that. Just copied the old code version for those two classes (from the previous question)

Comment: @takemyoxygen yeah ignore my comment - misunderstood what you were referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TComparer` is defined as inheriting `RoomComparer`.
That means that it implements `IComparer` of `Room`.
Your list contains instances of `TRoom`, which implements `IRoom`, not `Room`.

Answer (score 1):

Well first, you need to fix the errors in your `SquareMetersComparer` and `StandardMultipliedSquareMetersComparer` class. They are overriding `public override int Compare(IRoom a, IRoom b)` but they are supposed to override `public override int Compare(Room a, Room b)`.

Secondly, you want to use naked constraints between comparer and TRoom, as such:

```
where TRoom : class, IRoom 
where TComparer : IComparer<TRoom>, new()
```

Also, covariance works for `IComparer`, which means you can also specify such constraints, if necessary:

```
where TRoom : class, IRoom 
where TComparer : IComparer<IRoom>, new()
```

Comment: Sorry, that was the old code for those two classes - just copied them from my prev. question - they actually implement `Compare(Room a, Room b)`